# How to get the first word of the selected item (string) in a autosuggest text box (Jquery, c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The below method is used to search a patient from my data base.Both name and id is suggesting when I type a letter.

I want to know a way to **get only the id value** to another text box. How can I do that.

```
private string BindName()
            {
                DataTable dt = null;
                using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["orthopedics"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "select * from patient";
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            dt = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                output.Append("[");
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    output.Append("\"" + dt.Rows[i]["firstname"].ToString()+ dt.Rows[i]["nic"].ToString() + "\"");
                    if (i != (dt.Rows.Count - 1))
                    {
                        output.Append(",");
                    }
                }
                output.Append("];");
                return output.ToString();
            }
```

//jquery funtion

```
function LoadList() {
                 var ds = null;
                 ds = <%=listFilter %>
                       $("#txt").autocomplete({
                           source: ds
              });
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Search Patients"/>
```

Comment: just use document.getElementById('txt').value() then you can get the selected values..

Comment: don't create json manually, it is error prone and more work than needed when all languages have parsers for it. Also problem description is not at all clear

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your textbox with patient and id on **'change' event**. Once it is **fired**, you can get current text of your textbox and **split it**, so you can get only id. It is very simple. Let me know if you need some more explanation or example of code.

Comment: Yes I did it using  $('#txt').on('autocompletechange change', function (){  // split function and assign  it to a label }).change.    Now I have another issue.I want to get that label value to code behind function's query.once I run the query by clicking the button It is not working.I think when the button is clicking because of the page refreshing the label value is disappearing.Any idea  how to get that value? .The label is an asp label. Thanks.